# how can I cache a small part of image in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, caching, preview

How I can show the image in the app like the social network?

My meaning is I show a blurred preview of the image (not download completely) then if the user clicks on the image, app downloading the image completely and shows.

[image]

Comment: You could try using an AnimatedSwitcher to go from the blurred version to the not blurred version. Trigger it when the async load finishes. That's not the only way to do it, but it's pretty simple.

Comment: @scottstoll2017 thanks, but I can't download image completely, I want only download a small part of the image and when user click download completely

Comment: I don't think that's possible, how would the server break the file into only the part you want? I think what you might need is icons, then when the user clicks one it will then download the whole image.

Comment: @scottstoll2017  yes I did this work you say (use icon) but I don't want this.what I want is cache small part of the image and show to the user when user click cache whole image